# Placing a personalized string from a data extension field in an email

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, data, ampscript, extension

I have a link with a personalized string like below.

```
http://example.com?email=%%emailaddr%%
```

If i place this in an email than the personalized string %%emailaddr%% will resolve to the email address of the person the email is being sent to.

What i want to do is place this link alongside the personalized string in a Data Extension field and do a lookup on the Data Extension field and place it in the email. But from what i have tested this  does not work  as the if i pull the whole link  `http://example.com?email=%%emailaddr%%` from the data extension field the %%emailaddr%% will not resolve to the email address of the recipient.

Is what i am trying to do possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think*, if I understand you correctly, you simply need to look up the value, and use a `TreatAsContent()` function to evaluate it.

```
%%[ 
    SET @link = Lookup("MyDE", "Link", "emailAddress", emailaddr)
]%%

%%=TreatAsContent(v(@link))=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lookup to the Data Extension to retrieve the value, then it'll be referenced like `@DEColumn` in this example:

```
%%[
var @DEColumn1, @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @DEColumn1 = Lookup("DataExtensionName", "ReturnColumn", "LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
]%%
DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%
```

If the column is `emailaddr` in your *sending* data extension, then it will be available in the email context as `%%emailaddr%%`.